# get schema from .mdf database (sql server)

Tags: sql-server

I have a .mdf (and .ldf) file for a SQL Server (I think express) database. I want to just see/export the schema of the database, but would rather not install the full SQL Server just for this, as it is a bit heavy. Is there some tool that can give me the data or even just the schema, preferably small and no install?

Comment: **No.** In order to see anything from your `.mdf/.ldf` file, you **must** install some version of SQL Server: Express, Web, Developer - whatever. You cannot peek at the contents of those files without SQL Server. No way. No workaround. No trick. No hack. Just no way.

Comment: Well you can ask someone who has SQLServer installed to attach your db and dump schema and data for you.

Comment: @marc_s Do you know what the most light-weight option is? The SQL Server 2008 Express that is bundled with my VS2010 Ultimate requiers 1.6 GB.

Comment: There's a SQL Server Express without any tools or anything - but then the question is: how do you extract the schema? Using `sqlcmd` seems a bit unwieldy....